# What is the precedence of the limit operator?

Tags: limits

I would like to know the precedence of the $\lim$ operator.

For instance, given the following expression:

$$f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} u(x) + v(x)$$

Does the limit apply only to the term?

$$f(x)=\left(\lim_{x \to a} u(x)\right) + v(x)$$

Or does it apply to the entire expression?

$$f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} \left( u(x) + v(x)\right)$$

Comment: Your first expression is very ambiguous. I don't think there's a set precedence. Everyone just uses parenthesis so there's no confusion.

Comment: So, there are no precedence conventions? You always have to use parenthesis?

Comment: I don't think so. Using parenthesis makes everything clear.

Comment: Typically people do; taking a limit isn't as trivial a thing as doing arithmetic, so generally the context will tip you off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most textbooks I've seen the limit operator has higher precedence than addition/subtraction:

$$\lim_{x \to a} u(x) + v(x) \equiv \left(\lim_{x \to a} u(x)\right) + v(x)$$

Where it gets hairy is whether the limit operator has higher precedence than multiplication/division:

$$\lim_{x \to a} u(x) v(x) \stackrel?= \left(\lim_{x \to a} u(x)\right) v(x)$$

I don't think there's an established convention so you would have to guess from context.  *However*, it's usually a bad idea to *shadow* variables (to reuse the same variable symbol for both the variable in the limit and also another variable outside the limit).  So if you wanted to be absolutely clear, it's a good idea to write your equation as:

$$f(x) = \lim_{y \to a} u(y) + v(x)$$